# Importing matlab data in a loop using keywords from a cell

Tags: matlab

I have two cell arrays:

```
a1 = {K01 mainEEG.mat,K02 mainEEG.mat,K03 mainEEG.mat,....,K10 mainEEG.mat}
a2 = {K01 file1.mat',K02 file2.mat,K05 file3.mat}
```

Now I want to import files present in `a2` from `a1` using initial string as keyword i.e `K01`, `K02` and `K05`. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You should try doing this yourself. If you run into a problem you can't fix while trying, feel free to [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) **about that specific problem** (be sure to include a [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the keywords and files in a [containers.Map](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html).

Example:

```
a1Keys = {'K01', 'K02', .... 'K10'};
a1Files = {'mainEEG.mat', 'mainEEG.mat', ...., 'mainEEG.mat'};
a1Map = containers.Map(a1Keys, a1Files);
```

You can then take the keywords from a2 and access the map somewhat like this:

```
someKey = 'K01';
if a1Map.isKey(someKey)
    file = a1Map(someKey);
    load(file);
end
```